# caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseEther')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

soy algo novato y llevo unos días con este error:
"caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseEther')".
El proyecto en el que estoy trabajando trata de una cesta de la compra donde los productos están en una base de datos Postgres ubicada en un contenedor Docker; un backend con nodejs, un frontend con React.
Desde el componente Productos se renderiza la lista de los productos donde a traves del ID se accede al detalle y a digitar la cantiddad.
El componente Cesta renderiza la tabla de los productos elegidos y se procede al pago a través de un botón.
Los pagos se realizan a través de Metamask que se apoya a una red privada de ethereum que levanté en un contenedor Docker.
El problema surge cuando defino los parámetros de la transacción :

```js
const txParams={
 to: "cuenta del comercio",
 from: cuenta,
 value:ethers.utils.parseEther(total.toString()).toHexString()
    }
```

A continuacion el codigo completo del componente Cesta.jsx, imagino que parseEther se encuentra con un undefined que no es la variable total porque llega a esa linea con un valor numerico, la libreria ethers es correctamente importada, por lo tanto no acabo de entender donde está el probelma.

```js
import React, {useState , useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import { Context } from "../main"
import {ethers} from 'ethers'

export function Cesta (){
    const[estado, setEstado]=useContext(Context);
    const [cuenta, setCuenta]= useState(null);  
    const [txOk, setTxOk]= useState(null);  
    const [txRechazo, setTxRechazo]= useState(null);   
    
    //Suma lineas de la cesta
    const total = estado.cesta.reduce((acc, item)=> acc+item.total,0);

//Conexion a Metamask
useEffect(()=>{
    window.ethereum && window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts'
        }).then(cuentas =>{
          setCuenta(cuentas[0])
          ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (cuentas)=>{
              setCuenta(cuentas[0])
              })
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error, "Conectarse a Metamask");
      });
},[]);

//Funcion pagar:
async function pagar(){

  const txParams={
    to: "cuenta del comercio",
    from: cuenta,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(total.toString()).toHexString()
     }
     try{
       const tx= await ethereum.request({
         method:"eth_sendTransaction",
          params:[txParams]
          })
        setTxOk(tx)
        }catch (error){
         setTxRechazo(error)
      }
}

return <div>
   <table className="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Total</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
          {estado.cesta.map(i=>(
            <tr key={i.producto.product_id}>
              <td>{i.producto.product_id}</td>
              <td>{i.producto.product_name}</td>
              <td>{i.cantidad}</td>
              <td>{i.producto.unit_price}</td>
              <td style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>{total}</td>
             </tr>
             ))}
          </tbody>
   </table> 
    <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Total {total}</h2>
    <h5>Cuenta:</h5>
    <h5>{cuenta}</h5>      
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>pagar()}>Pagar</button>
   {txOk && <p className="alert alert-sucess">{txOk} </p>}
  {txRechazo && <p> {txRechazo}</p>}
 </div> 
}
```

Espero haya facilitado toda la informacion necesaria y agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda por vuestra parte.
un saludo
kiko

Comment: Lo primero que sugiero intentar es cambiar el valor de esta propiedad `onClick={()=>pagar()}` por `onClick={pagar}`